# dnsmasq reads addn-hosts config but ignores it, falls back to system's /etc/hosts

Tags: linux-networking, fedora, dnsmasq, networkmanager

I'm running `dnsmasq` installed as a `NetworkManager` plugin on my local Fedora 39 machine.
All I need from `dnsmasq` is basically support for additional `hosts` files that I can organise by topics.

My configs are:

1. `/etc/dnsmasql.conf`:

```
user=dnsmasq
group=dnsmasq
interface=lo
bind-interfaces
conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d,*.conf
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d,.rpmnew,.rpmsave,.rpmorig
```

2. `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/00-use-dnsmasq.conf`

```
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

3. `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/00-add-hosts.conf`

```
log-queries
no-hosts
addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.d
address=/development/127.0.0.1
```

4. `/etc/hosts.d` is a directory with the hosts files that contain entries I want to "sinkhole":

```
0.0.0.0 1.example.com
0.0.0.0 2.example.com
...
```

`dnsmasq` is up and running, I see the daemon in my processes:

```
ps aux | grep dnsmasq

dnsmasq    61161  0.4  0.0 228096  4480 ?        S    16:08   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.0.1 --cache-size=400 --clear-on-reload --conf-file=/dev/null --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

I also see in the `dnsmasq` debug logs, that hosts files from `/etc/hosts.d` are read too:

```
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: chown of PID file /run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid failed: Operation not permitted
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: DBus support enabled: connected to system bus
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: warning: no upstream servers configured
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: read /etc/hosts.d/private - 10 names
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Dec 30 16:18:40 fedora dnsmasq[61823]: using nameserver 192.168.0.1#53(via wlp2s0)
```

But when I try to access domains from the `addn-hosts` hosts files,
they aren't resolved to `0.0.0.0` as I'd expect. These hosts files
seem to be ignored.

On the other hand, anything that I add to system's `/etc/hosts` works
as expected. Even though I used `no-hosts` options explicitly in the
`dnsmasq` config and I see that it's added to the daemon invocation.

I alos see that `dnsmasq` config is used, because
the `address=/development/127.0.0.1` line works as expected:

```
$ ping -c 3 anything.development
PING anything.development (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.175 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.200 ms
```

It's just `addn-hosts` that is ignored somehow.

Here's my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options edns0 trust-ad
```

Previously I thought that it's `systemd-resolved.service` that
interferes (as it previously added 127.0.0.53 to my `resolv.conf`
file), but now that I disabled the service:

```
systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
○ systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done a good job of describing the situation but you can be more particular about testing the name resolution you're seeing. Do you have `dig` or `nslookup` as command-line tools on your system? If so, please use them to query the on-machine nameserver directly rather than whatever you did.

> But when I try to access domains from the addn-hosts hosts files, they
> aren't resolved to 0.0.0.0 as I'd expect. These hosts files seem to be
> ignored.

I'm seeing that you don't have an upstream name server defined in your config (and yet obviously you are using an upstream name server.) I suspect that the resolution for the blacklisted domains is actually coming from your upstream.  So the first question I'd ask is: Does my local `dnsmasq` instance correctly respond?

Here's what success looks like for me:

```
tai@fay:~ $ dig adserver.com          

; <<>> DiG 9.16.44-Raspbian <<>> adserver.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 18567
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;adserver.com.                  IN      A

;; Query time: 259 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 31 16:12:15 EST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 41
```

Note the `SERVER:` field in 3rd-to-last line reassures me I am asking my local server. You can specify a server name or IP address after the question in this way, which happens to show a normal resolution (which is what we don't want in this case):

```
tai@fay:~ $ dig adserver.com @8.8.8.8      

; <<>> DiG 9.16.44-Raspbian <<>> adserver.com @8.8.8.8
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23032
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;adserver.com.                  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
adserver.com.           5400    IN      A       159.127.40.163

;; Query time: 119 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 31 16:11:57 EST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 57
```

(This system I'm using here is quite similar to your set-up but 1) it's a dedicated DNS/DHCP machine and 2) I do not have the added complication of modularizing my dnsmasq through NetworkManager.)

DNS can get pretty complicated in situations like this and I'm not surprised neither you nor I can immediately see what the problem is. Try probing your local dnsmasq specifically, and also add some details about where resolution is occurring, if not from your dnsmasq!

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helpful advice! You set mt in the right direction with my troubleshooting! Ah, I simply haven't figured out that what `/etc/resolv.conf` says isn't what `NetworkManager` is necessary using when deciding what DNS to use (`dig` and `nslookup` are dumber in this respect!). So, I posted my entire troubleshooting process [separately](https://serverfault.com/questions/1150701/dnsmasq-reads-addn-hosts-config-but-ignores-it-falls-back-to-systems-etc-host/1150735#1150735), in case someone else will find it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved thanks to the great advice from [@Tai Viinikka](https://serverfault.com/users/199210/tai-viinikka)!

TLDR; A DNS server from `dnsmasq` running on localhost doesn't
necessary mean it's used by the `NetworkManager`, even if the
`/etc/resolv.conf` says explicitly so; If your local machine is using
your router's DHCP server, you got DNS server settings from it too.

TIL; `dig` uses a DNS server from `/etc/resolv.conf` by default, even
if a connection managed by the `NetworkManager` uses DNS server
address obtained from the DHCP; hence the difference how `dig` and,
say, `curl` resolve the same hostname.

Troubleshooting:

1. Check, if my localhost DNS from `dnsmasq` is indeed working as expected:

```
# dig or nslookup a host from my addn-hosts's hosts file
$ dig 1.example.com
[...]
;; ANSWER SECTION:
1.example.com.      0   IN  A   0.0.0.0
[...]
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) (UDP)
```

Hostname resolved to `0.0.0.0` (as stated by `addn-hosts` hosts file)
by the `127.0.0.1` (`dnsmasq` local DNS server) as expected.

Why then all the all the requests from `curl` or a browser to the same
hostname got resolved not though my local DNS from `dnsmasq`, but,
obviously, from another upstream DNS, despite `/etc/resolv.conf`
saying:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options edns0 trust-ad
```

That mean something is overriding DNS settings. Must be `NetworkManager`

2. Check what `NetworkManager` is using as DNS:

```
$ nmcli device show | grep -i dns
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2a02:8383:d:c::1000
IP6.DNS[2]:                             2a02:8383:d:c::1
```

Indeed, instead of what `/etc/resolv.conf` says, `NetworkManager` uses
my WiFi router's DNS addresses. This is because a WiFI connection on
my local machine uses router's `DHCP` settings.

3. Set upstream DNS servers in `dnsmasq`

Before fixing DNS used by the `NetworkManager`, we need to add some
upstream DNS that will be used once hosts files are checked. Here's
how my whole `dnsmasq` config looks like now:

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/00-add-hosts.conf

# NB! When making changes, don't forget restart dnsmasq & NetworkManager.service:
# $ killall dnsmasq
# $ systemctl restart NetworkManager

# No need to read /etc/resolv.conf as it contains the localhost
# addresses of dnsmasq itself
no-resolv

# Upstream DNS servers
# My router, Google, CloudFlare
server=192.168.0.1
server=8.8.8.8
server=1.1.1.1

# Add debug logging
# $ journalctl --follow -u NetworkManager
log-queries

# Ignore /etc/hosts
no-hosts

# Add custom hosts files; 
# If path is a directory, all files from it are loaded
addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.d
```

4. Fix DNS servers in `NetworkManager`'s connection settings:

Open up `nm-connection-editor` (or Settings -> WiFi -> Network you're
connected to Settings), then `IPv4`:

- Method -> Automatic (DHCP) addresses only
- DNS Server -> 127.0.0.1 (instead of automatic one)

then for `IPv6`:

- Method -> Automatic, DHCP only (watch out, it's different than for `IPv4`)

This corresponds to the changes in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YOUR-CONNECTION-NAME.nmconnection`:

```
[ipv4]
dns=127.0.0.1;
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns=::1;
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=dhcp
```

Now, restart the `dnsmasq` and the `NetworkManager`:

```
$ sudo killall dnsmasq
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

et voilà! `NetworkManager` uses localhost as a DNS server, all
requests from `curl` or a web browser get resolved using it, extra
hosts files from `dnsmasq`'s `addn-hosts` are respected:

```
$ nmcli device show | grep -i dns
IP4.DNS[1]:                             127.0.0.1
IP6.DNS[1]:                             ::1
```

```
$ curl -v 1.example.com
* processing: 1.example.com
*   Trying 0.0.0.0:80...
* connect to 0.0.0.0 port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying [2604:a880:400:d0::2082:1001]:80...
* Immediate connect fail for 2604:a880:400:d0::2082:1001: Network is unreachable
* Failed to connect to lobste.rs port 80 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
```